# Wxpython: Multiple panel not showing

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, panel

I am making a budgeting program that displays all the user's expenses. I want to have it so that when the user clicks on the ListUI, it displays all the data about the category. I can get the program to switch between two category panels, however I can't get the Summary page to display properly. It is just blank without any information.

(Bonus points for positioning the panels beside the List UI, something I want to learn buy haven't gotten to yet.)

```
#In my budget module
    def displayBudget(self,panel,sizer):

        self.categoryListUI = wx.ListCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY,style = wx.LC_REPORT) 
        self.categoryPanelList = []
        self.categoryListUI.InsertColumn(0, 'Name',width = 75)
        self.categoryListUI.InsertColumn(1, 'Amount',width = 100)        
        self.categoryListUI.InsertColumn(2, 'Spending',width = 100)  
        self.categoryListUI.InsertColumn(3, 'Remaining',width = 100)

        index = 0
        self.insertListCtrlSummary(self.categoryListUI,index,panel)
        tempCatPanel = self.displaySummary(panel)
        tempCatPanel.Hide()
        self.categoryPanelList.append(tempCatPanel)

        index += 1
    
        for i in self.categoryArray:

            i.insertListCtrl(self.categoryListUI,index,panel)

            tempCatPanel = i.displayCategory(panel)
            tempCatPanel.Hide()
            self.categoryPanelList.append(tempCatPanel)

            index += 1

        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnClick, self.categoryListUI)

        sizer.Add(self.categoryListUI,pos=(2, 0),span=(1, 100),flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM, border = 5)

        self.currentPanel = self.categoryPanelList[0]
        self.currentPanel.Update()
        self.currentPanel.Show()

        sizer.Add(self.currentPanel ,pos=(25, 25),span=(4, 8),flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, border = 5)

        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
    
        print(len(self.categoryPanelList))

        return sizer

    def OnClick(self,event):

        if self.currentPanel != None:
            self.currentPanel.Hide()
        print(event.GetIndex())   
        self.currentPanel = self.categoryPanelList[event.GetIndex()]

        if self.currentPanel is None:

            wx.MessageBox('Could not display Category.', 'Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)

        else:

            self.currentPanel.Update()
            self.currentPanel.Show()

    def insertListCtrlSummary(self,uiList,index,panel):
        self.categoryListUI.InsertItem(index, "Summary")
        self.categoryListUI.SetItem(index, 1, "$ "+str(format(self.amount, '.2f')))
        self.categoryListUI.SetItem(index, 2, "$ "+str(format(self.totalSpending(), '.2f')))
        self.categoryListUI.SetItem(index, 3, "$ "+str(format(self.totalRemaining(), '.2f') ))

    def displaySummary(self,parent):

        panel = wx.Panel(parent)
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        remainString = "Remaining: $ "+str(self.totalRemaining())
        remainStatic = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, remainString)
        amountStatic = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Amount: $ ") 
        amountDisplay = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, str(self.amount))
        sizer.Add(amountStatic,pos=(0, 0),span=(1, 1),flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, border = 5)
        sizer.Add(amountDisplay,pos=(0, 1),span=(1, 1),flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, border = 5)
        sizer.Add(remainStatic,pos=(0, 4),span=(1, 3),flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, border = 5)

        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        
        panel.Show()

        return panel
```

```
#Category display stuff.

    def insertListCtrl(self,uiList,index,panel):
        uiList.InsertItem(index, self.name) 
        uiList.SetItem(index, 1, "$ "+str(format(self.amount, '.2f'))) 
        uiList.SetItem(index, 2, "$ "+str(format(self.calculateExpenses(), '.2f')))
        uiList.SetItem(index, 3, "$ "+str(format(self.calculateRemainingAmount(), '.2f')))

    def displayCategory(self,panelMaster):
        
        panel = wx.Panel(panelMaster)
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        remainString = "Remaining: $ "+ str(format(self.calculateRemainingAmount(), '.2f'))
        remainStatic = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, remainString)
        amountStatic = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Amount: $ ") 
        amountDisplay = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, str(format(self.amount, '.2f')))
        sizer.Add(amountStatic,pos=(0, 0),span=(1, 1),flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, border = 5)
        sizer.Add(amountDisplay,pos=(0, 1),span=(1, 1),flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, border = 5)
        sizer.Add(remainStatic,pos=(0, 4),span=(1, 3),flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, border = 5)
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

        return panel
```

Comment: Several things: do not create the panel when displaying it. Create it before and hide it. When you need it, fill it in with the information and show it. I highly recommend that you use WxGlade to build the graphical part with wxPython.

Comment: Sadly, the code snippets that you have posted, provide us with nothing more than a bag of code spanners. Without an idea of how these things hang together, I doubt that you will receive a useful answer. Either post the full code or https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example